# Keyboard shortcuts for Offline Google Mail (Gmail)?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, google-apps-email

With the [Offline Google Mail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk) app in the Chrome Web Store, is it possible to enable keyboard shortcuts similar to those available in the [web version of Gmail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594)?

For example, I can use the mouse to move the scroll bar, but the up/down arrows only jump from one message to the next, I can not figure out how to scroll the message itself.

To be clear, I am not using the old version of gmail offline, which was supported  by google gears, but the new version supported by HTML5.

Comment: The only thing I found so far is to use page up/down to move through the message. Will be good if someone tells how to move throughout the message in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversations can be scrolled with <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd>. If you have keyboard shortcuts enabled, you can simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and see the entire list of shortcuts supported by GMail Offline.

Comment: how can I enable keyboard shortcuts? Under settings, I only see the option to enable a vacation responder. To be clear, I am not using the old version of gmail offline, which was supported  by google gears, but the new version supported by HTML5.

Comment: Well, given that Google Gears are no longer supported, there's only 1 current version of GMail Offline. Keyboard shortcuts are turned on/off by the setting in the online interface (3rd from top in the General tab).

Comment: I don't see any tabs in the interface. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Go to regular GMail. Click the cog-wheel to the left of the pagination buttons on top of the list of emails. Click on `Settings`. You'll be taken to the General tab. The 3rd option from top is going to be `Keyboard Shortcuts`. Enable it.

Comment: they were already enabled - I use them in regular GMail all the time.

Comment: Then go ahead and use Page Up & Page Down to scroll messages in offline.

Comment: yesterday, it did not work, but today it does.

Comment: @David You can click `?` to see the list of shortcuts in the offline Gmail as well. Then, you have the option to enable/disable the shortcuts from there.

Answer (score 1):

These days, even when shortcuts are disabled in gmail, you can enter <kbd>?</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to see the available keyboard shortcuts. From the resulting popup you can then enable/disable the shortcuts directly.

Answer (score 0):

Important shortcut, when you're in the compose dialog and want to send your message: <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>